# Why does ParamStr show the wrong file name?

Tags: delphi, paramstr

I have associated the ".file_5" extension with my application and I used the ParamStr(1) function in Delphi to show a messagebox that contains the path & file name of the file when I double click on it in explorer using the code below.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 var
  TheFile : string;
begin
  TheFile := ParamStr(1);  //filename for the file that was loaded
  ShowMessage(TheFile);
end;
```

This works, but if I move the file to another location then the location it was originally in, then the message that is shown is not correct.

Example: (using test.file_5)

The original location of the file is in the C:\ drive and when I double click it my application starts and displays a Messagebox that says:

> C:\test.file_5

This is correct. If I move that same file to a directory that contains spaces like the program file folder for example then the Messagbox that is displayed is not

> C:\Program Files\test.file_5

like I would expect but rather

> C:\PROGRA~1.FILE_

which is obviously not the information I am after so my question is how can I use the ParamStr() function to take into account directories that have spaces in them or is there a better function that I should use that works with directories that contains spaces in them.

Comment: Are you really saying that the file name *still* returns the name of a file that's in the root directory even though it's now in the Program Files directory? And that the file extension is reduced from six characters to five? And that the "test" portion of the name is completely removed? That doesn't sound right. Please edit your question to make it accurately describe what you're seeing.

Comment: It is accurate (as others have had no problem understanding it) so I suggest you read it again or stay out of this topic entirely since your presence here is not helpful at all.

Comment: I think @Rob presence here is very helpful (as his almost 40,000 Rep may suggest to you) and I think you should appreciate he is taking the time to read and comment.  Also I agree with Rob that you didn't copy the filename you're really seeing when you post here.  The fact I understood what you want doesn't mean Rob is wrong, just maybe I'm not as strict as he is.

Comment: BTW, @Rob also takes the time to think for a more accurate post title, and edit it.  Did you notice that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your association is set up wrong. Instead of having double_clicking the .file_5 doing

```
C:\YourPath\YourApp.exe %1
```

The association should be set up as

```
"C:\YourPathYourApp.exe" "%1"
```

Notice the double quotes around the %1 - this keeps any spaces contained instead of their causing Windows to pass the short path and filename.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the way I setup the association in the first place so I could avoid using a function at all.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 15):

This is not neccesarily wrong... is just explorer is passing a short file name to your program -instead of the long file name-.  See [short vs. long names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names).

You can open the file using both names or you can convert from short to long file name before the ShowMessage (or actually manipulating the file) if you're concerned about working with long file names only. Use the [GetLongPathName API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364980%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) call, defined in Windows.pas.

```
function ShortToLongFileName(const ShortName: string): string;
var
  outs: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  GetLongPathName(PChar(ShortName), OutS, MAX_PATH);
  Result := OutS;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TheFile : string;
begin
  TheFile := ParamStr(1);  //filename for the file that was loaded
  TheFile := ShortToLongFileName(TheFile);
  ShowMessage(TheFile);
end;
```

I tested it under Windows Vista and GetLongPathName works whether you supply a short or a already long file name (if the file exists, obviusly)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's appreciated and I understood the problem was the long path name but did not know how to convert the short to long name. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it on my own using this function.

```
Function GetLongPathAndFilename(Const S : String) : String;
```

Var
   srSRec             : TSearchRec;
   iP,iRes            : Integer;
   sTemp,sRest        : String;
   Bo                 : Boolean;

Begin
Result := S + ' [directory not found]';
// Check if file exists
Bo := FileExists(S);
// Check if directory exists
iRes := FindFirst(S + '*.*',faAnyFile,srSRec);
// If both not found then exit
If ((not Bo) and (iRes <> 0)) then
      Exit;
sRest := S;
iP := Pos('\',sRest);
If iP > 0 then
   Begin
   sTemp := Copy(sRest,1,iP - 1); // Drive
   sRest := Copy(sRest,iP + 1,255); // Path and filename
   End
else
   Exit;
// Get long path name
While Pos('\',sRest) > 0 do
   begin
   iP := Pos('\',sRest);
   If iP > 0 then
      Begin
      iRes := FindFirst(sTemp + '\' + Copy(sRest,1,iP - 1),faAnyFile,srSRec);
      sRest := Copy(sRest,iP + 1,255);
      If iRes = 0 then
      sTemp := sTemp + '\' + srSRec.FindData.cFileName;
      End;
   End;
// Get long filename
If FindFirst(sTemp + '\' + sRest,faAnyFile,srSRec) = 0 then
   Result := sTemp + '\' + srSRec.FindData.cFilename;
SysUtils.FindClose(srSRec);
End;

Comment: You should prefer the `GetLongPathName` function which is especially provided for this task.

Comment: This function is grossly incorrect. Its return value on error is indistinguishable from a valid file name. It doesn't recognize directories correctly. It makes invalid assumptions about the lengths of file names. It leaks system resources like a sieve.

Comment: Nice response Rob. Instead of just criticizing the code and leaving it at that you should at least provide a better solution.

Comment: BTW I did not write the function, I did as most people would do and searched for an answer that "worked for me" on google and despite all of it's shortcomings it did "work for me" in my test and was "trying" to help others who had the same problem.

Comment: Andrew, I don't think Rob's feedback was meant as a personal attack, so try to not take it as such.